# can't comunicate between a publisher and a subscriber on the same machine but with another machine ros master uri

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so i have a raspberry pi and a pc both runing ros ,the publisher and the subscriber are both located in the raspberry pi when i rosrun the both nodes with the rasberry pi being the master everthing works the two nodes can communicate but when i change the master uri on the raspberry pi with the ip of the other pc and launch the two nodes the subscriber code can't subscribe it returns nothing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365020/can%27t-comunicate-between-a-publisher-and-a-subscriber-on-the-same-machine-but-with-another-machine-ros-master-uri/) by [med97](https://answers.ros.org/users/62838/med97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a *very*  common issue, which is why I've created a gist script to set it up correctly, together with some troubleshooting steps: https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [med97](https://answers.ros.org/users/62838/med97/) on 2020-11-07**:
thank you sir it worked , the problem was that i did not set the ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP for both pi and pc

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-11-07**:
Glad it helped! Please don't forget to upvote the answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-08**:
@chfritz: thank you for answering the question, but could you please not post link-only answers? If/when your gist changes or disappears (and this does happen more frequently than you might think), this answer will lose all its value.

It would be great if you could include the relevant parts from your gist here in your answer, and then also explain what users are seeing, such that it becomes less of a magic incantation they'll just copy-paste.

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-11-08**:
Hi Gijs, I know what you are getting at, but at the same time we do this sort of thing all the time when we point people at a package or some other ros tool that solves their problem. Granted, packages are perhaps better maintained than gists (perhaps!), but certainly in both cases the benefit is that the outside resource can continue to improve. Maybe the best option would be to move the snippet of my gist over to the ros wiki somewhere? Do you think that would be better?